# Axios cai no catch mesmo com status code 200

Tags: react-native, axios

Tenho um codigo de login, que quando um utilizador inicia sessão se os dados estiverem incorrectos um backend feito em nodejs retorna um erro 401 e se estiver tudo correto retorna um status code de 200.

Durante a execução do código, quando o utilizador se engana nos dados ele executa a função correctamente "catch", mas se ele coloca tudo correto ele não sei por alma de quem executa o then mas também o "catch".

Alguém me poderia ajudar com este problema?

```
        async function handleLogin(){
        await AsyncStorage.removeItem('Authorization');
        await AsyncStorage.removeItem('ImAuthenticated');
        await api.post('/login', {
            email,
            password
        }, {
            headers: { 'device': 'mobile' }
        }).then(async(response)=>{
            const { hash } = response.data;
            await AsyncStorage.setItem("Authorization", hash);
            await AsyncStorage.setItem("ImAuthenticated", true);
            navigation.navigate('Menu');
            console.log('oi');
        }).catch(function (error){
            if(error.response.data.showIn == "text"){
                setShowInfo(true);
                setEmail('');
                setPass('');
                this.InEmail.focus();
                if(error.response.data.level == 3){
                    setColorInfo(false);
                }else{
                    setColorInfo(true);
                }
                setInfoText(error.response.data.error);
            }else{
                setshowBox(true);
                setEmail('');
                setPass('');
                this.InEmail.focus();
                if(error.response.data.level == 3){
                    setcolorBox(false);
                }else{
                    setcolorBox(true);
                }
                setboxText(error.response.data.error);
        }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Opa, eu imagino que se sua requisição retorna 200, o problema não é nela e sim em alguma lógica dentro do response da sua requisição...

pode ser o AsyncStorage, ou navigation. Eles estão importados corretamente ?

**IMPORTANTE:** para vc saber o que está de errado no response da sua requisição, coloque um console.log no catch.
`.catch(function (error){ console.log('erro', error ); }`
dai vc olha no console e com certeza vai ter clareza do que deu errado.

Comente aqui o problema que o catch apontou caso não consiga resolver.

Answer (score 0):

Se você está utilizando o `async\await` não é necessário utilizar o `resolve\reject`. Tente modificar seu código para:

```js
// ...
try {
    const dados = await api.post('/login',
                                 { email, password },
                                 { headers: { 'device': 'mobile' } }
    );

    // ...
    console.log(dados);
    // ...
} catch (err) {
    console.log('Erro no api.post', err);
}
```

ou sem o `async/await`:

```js
api.post('/login',
         { email, password },
         { headers: { 'device': 'mobile' } }
).then(dados => {
    // ...
    console.log(dados);
    // ...
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```